# Toggle layout animations in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, layout-animation

I have layout animations properly configured as shown in all tutorials / documentation listed below. I'm currently setting the Layout Animation configurations in the componentWillUpdate method and triggering **ON** works smoothly,

```
componentWillUpdate() {
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(animationConfig);
```

}

..although the problem is that I need to trigger the animation **OFF**. The animation persists throughout the application, creating animations that are not intended...

I found only one solution, which is to trigger: `LayoutAnimation.configureNext(animationConfig);`
when the animation is no longer needed.. although this seems like not best practice because it interrupts the LayoutAnimation, thus, spinning up warnings..

There's very little documentation or questions about this.. I need some clarification on how to properly handle toggling layout animations.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html
https://medium.com/@Jpoliachik/react-native-s-layoutanimation-is-awesome-4a4d317afd3e